# xt::xexpression is protected within this context

Tags: c++, xtensor

Consider the following code:

```
#include <chrono>                                                                                        
#include <iostream>

#include "xtensor/xadapt.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xindex_view.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        xt::expression<float> a = xt::zeros<float>({3, 256, 256});
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration<double> time = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    cout << time.count() << endl;
}
```

This fails to compile, with the following error: `test.cpp:24:66: error: ‘xt::xexpression<D>::~xexpression() [with D = float]’ is protected within this context`.
When changing `xt::xexpression<float>` [(the correct return type)](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xbuilder.html?highlight=zeros#_CPPv4I00EN2xt5zerosEDa1S) to `auto` it compiles and runs. If `xt::expression` is protected, why can `auto` access it? and is there a way I can specify the type rather than use `auto`, without evaluating the xexpression? (i.e. I can't have the type of `a` be `xt::xarray`, because this forces evaluation).

Comment: The documentation says that it returns an `xexpression`, but maybe it returns a type derived from `xexpression` and you aren't supposed to use `xexpression` directly? I'm not familiar with this library. How do you know that `xexpression<float>` is the right return type?

Comment: Just reading the documentation. I suppose I could be wrong. Either I read the docs wrong (probably), or the docs weren't correct (less probable). When you say derived, do you mean inheritance? i.e. `xt::zeros` returns a child class of `xexpression`? could be, but I don't know why they wouldn't just say that in the docs.

Comment: Is there a way I could check what type auto is being resolved to?

Comment: You could try to do something you aren't allowed to do to the result and have the compiler tell you what it is. e.g. `auto a = xt::zeros<float>(...); void impossible(int); impossible(a);` You should get an error like `error: cannot convert _____' to 'int' ...` (assuming the conversion actually fails).

Comment: Indeed it is not an `xexpression`. it's of type `xt::xbroadcast<xt::xscalar<float>, std::array<long unsigned int, 3> >`

Comment: Downvotes are probably lack of [mre], but with downvotes it's always hard to be sure.

Comment: I also assumed downvotes to be due to lack of a [mre].  You are asking about an error on line 24 from code that has no line 24.

Comment: So it's just the lack of #includes? I can fix that.

Answer (score 2):

`Auto` is not resolving to `xexpression`, but a child of `xexpression`, as Kevin pointed out in the comments. Changing the type to `xt::xbroadcast<xt::xscalar<float>, std::array<long unsigned int, 3> >` will compile without evaluating.